# I want to get the number of followers for a certain day, but no data is stored in `data` and it returns

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I executed an API like below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{PAGE_ID}/insights?metric=follower_count&period=day&since=1706717975&until=1706668799&access_token={TOKEN_ID}
```

Then the following value was returned

```json
{
    "data": [
      
    ],
    "paging": ...
       "next": ...
    }
}
```

There is no value stored in the `data` property.
How can I store the value in the `data` property and retrieve the number of followers on a certain date?

Comment: Your since and until values are the timestamps for `Wed Jan 31 2024 16:19:35 GMT+0000` and `Wed Jan 31 2024 02:39:59 GMT+0000`. So your since is greater than your until, plus the whole thing isn't even a full day.